# Difference between sending strings and sending objects via tcp to android client from java server

Tags: java, android, tcp

I could successfully create a chat application between Android Client and Java Server via TCP. It was done by sending text data(Strings) using PrintWriter and BufferedReader. However, to send objects between Android and Java Server using ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStreams, I was told it was a bad practice and JSON was recommended. I dont understand why sending and receiving objects wouldn't work the same way the chat application did. Can anyone provide a deep insight into this situation?

Comment: The structure of an object can depend on many factors (programming language, computer architecture). By using a standard format (such as JSON) you can abstract away from those differences. That way, you can have a Android client and a C# client both using a PHP server, for instance. With strings, you don't have this issue, because it is a default format already.

Comment: The object I wanna send has only primitive data types. Will the object be affected if I use only ObjectStreams without using JSON?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no problem at all between a Java server and an Android client, no matter how complex the data. JSON is probably easier to debug and test though, because the data is readable.